# Jquery blur() anomaly

Tags: jquery, ajax

say i have a validation of email id using `blur()` event , im doing this :

```
$('#email').blur(function(){
    //make ajax call , check if duplicate email exist and if duplicate is there do :
    $('#email-error').html('duplicate email exisit');
});
```

however when i use `blur()` and if im on a input box , click somewhere else (blur event occurs) and if i switch to another tab and again come back to the tab(of the browser) my page freezes, can someone give me an alternative, to this ?

Comment: need a really really quick fix for this , puhllease help

Comment: The browser freezing sounds more like a browser issue/bug than a javascript issue. You're using Firefox I'm guessing?

Comment: @ClickUpvote ooh absolutely , it(was thanks to @sibu) happening in chrome and IE not firefox , soo but im really curious why blur() caused it and why change() doesnt

Comment: see answer with more description on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367899/check-if-record-exists-in-mysql-database-on-blur/12369056#12369056

Comment: @RajatModi sure that answers his question there is not reason why blur() freezes my screen and why change() doesnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of blur use **[.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** function.The change event is sent to an element when its value changes.Your **blur event** or **focusout event** will unnecessary fire ajax request everytime your textbox looses focus whether the data has changed or not.

```
$('#email').change(function(){
   //make ajax call , check if duplicate email exist and if duplicate is there do :
   $('#email-error').html('duplicate email exisit');
});
```

Comment: my friend , thou art genius , *bows* , but dont u think change will occur even if im still on that input box ? i should allow user to enter the email completely and when he goes to other field of register that time the trigger to ajax call should be fired ?

Comment: @user1537158 change event will be called only when the user moves to next field check this http://jsfiddle.net/SCs7w/1/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of blur add like this

```
$('#email').focusout(function(){  
    $('#email-error').html('duplicate email exisit');
});
```

Comment: focusout i tried instead of blur , the same anomaly exists , i guess change() is working perfect till now

Comment: on focusout we can put the validations also.then your ajax wont work..??

Comment: no no focusout has the same effect that iv described in my question